# Reading in a web based text file I am getting a ton of errors with json()

Tags: python, json, parsing, text-files

I am getting a bunch of errors with respect to the json function. My code is below and it's pretty straight forward. I am trying to request this text file on the web and write it to a new file. Then parse the data to get the first IP address in each row. I am first just trying to get past all of these errors.

```
#extracting text from website https://isc.sans.edu/block.txt

import requests
import json

url = "https://isc.sans.edu/block.txt"

webtext = requests.get(url).json()

# writing to file
webtextfile = open('webtextfile.txt', 'w')
webtextfile.writelines(str(webtext))
webtextfile.close()
  
# Using readlines()
webtextfile = open('webtextfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = webtextfile.readlines()

print(Lines)

#parsing the lines
```

Errors below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allen/Education/Masters/VT/5480/Project_6/P6.py", line 8, in <module>
    webtext = requests.get(url).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am getting a bunch of errors with respect to the json function. My code is below and it's pretty straight forward. I am trying to request this text file on the web and write it to a new file. Then parse the data to get the first IP address in each row. I am first just trying to get past all of these errors.

I have tried without json. but I am not completely sure why I am using json.

Comment: You're getting a JSON decoding error because the file isn't JSON.

Comment: Yeah, as woodford mentioned that page isn't json data. It's a text file. You could try `webtext = requests.get(url).text` instead of `webtext = requests.get(url).json()`.

Comment: I ended up using beautifulsoup instead. I have to parse the data from that website and extract just the first IP in each row, while ignoring the lines starting with #. any recomendations on how I can extract these IP addresses and add them to a list?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly optimized but it works and probably can be fixed up a bit. As mentioned in the comments you were trying to read the site as json data when it is a text file so I changed `webtext = requests.get(url).json()` to `webtext = requests.get(url).text`  and added some parsing below your line `Lines = webtextfile.readlines()`.

So the data you want starts at the first line without a '#" so the first for loop will count up until it doesn't find the '#'. This line would be the header.  After that loop through starting at the header+1. This would be the table data. Each row is in its own list so you just need the first element from that list which is the ip column you need.

Explanations in code block as well.

```
#extracting text from website https://isc.sans.edu/block.txt

import requests
import json

url = "https://isc.sans.edu/block.txt"

webtext = requests.get(url).text

# webtext = webtext.split()
# writing to file
webtextfile = open('webtextfile.txt', 'w')
webtextfile.writelines(str(webtext))
webtextfile.close()
  
# Using readlines()
webtextfile = open('webtextfile.txt', 'r')

Lines = webtextfile.readlines()

# clean the text from Lines which is a list and split on tab,newslines,whitespaces
# cleaned will become a list of lists
cleaned = [item.split() for item in Lines]
count = 0
start_position = 0

# if the item contains a '#' keep counting up if it doesn't that's the start position
for line in cleaned:
    if "#" in line:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        start_position = count
        break


# skip header. (currently it would be at the header line. beginning with 'start')
start_position += 1
ip_list = []
for i in range(start_position,len(Lines)):
    #each row is its own list 
    print(cleaned[i])
    #element 0 will be the ip
    ip_list.append(cleaned[i][0])

print(ip_list)
```